# Binding unicode to gridviewcolumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, unicode

I have a listview that is right now showing the consumption and production og electricity, water and heat. But i need to show the unit of these different values. 
I'm currently trying to use a char variable with unicode that i have binded to the gridviewcolumn that is showing the unit, but it wont show the unit sign.

```
switch (type)
{
    case "water":       unit = '\u33A5'; break;
    case "electricity": unit = '\u33BE'; break;
    case "heat":        unit = '\u33BF'; break;
}
```

my binding looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvSearch" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=RegistrationWithKeyNumbers}" Visibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="125" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvcPeriode" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Consumption}" Width="150"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Unit}" Header="Enhed" Width="40"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

What i get right now is just squares.

EDIT:
My entire Unit Property in my class looks like this:

```
protected char unit;

public char Unit
{
    get { return this.unit; }
    set
    {
        if (this.unit != value)
        {
            this.unit = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Unit");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show code for complete `Unit` property, not just some random piece of code.

Comment: My guess you are setting `unit` *after* binding happened and since there is no notifications the change does not get reflected in the view. (Assuming you `switch` code is the way you set `unit`)

Comment: the switch code is used before i add a new RegistrationWithKeyNumbers to my list that i bind with. But maybe you know something on the comment there is down in the first answer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a font that doesn't support those Unicode characters?

Comment: I'm using the standard font i don't know if that supports?

Comment: I just tried it with a textbox that has the same font and it works

Comment: Are you sure the Binding is getting updated? `unit` in your switch statement is lowercase, which means OnPropertyChanged() will not get fired. Also, even if something else is somehow firing OnPropertyChanged(), it's possible `RegistrationWithKeyNumbers` is not bubbling up the notifications, making the ListView never update.

Comment: I just made it work by changing my unit variable to string instead of char.

Could the problem be something with binding char to listview?

Comment: That was actually my first idea, but never mentioned it. Perhaps WPF doesn't have an automatic way to display char. It's entirely possible that the TextBox was doing its own conversion to string before trying to display it.

Comment: the databinding way on a textbox i believe you are right. Coding a textbox.Text = char.ToString(); 
Made me think maybe i need the unicode to be held in a string variable.